# Regular expression for anything except ']]' characters

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I had posted a question earlier but it wasn't very clear to understand so it here goes again:

I have a string which looks like this :

```
{
"1000":[ [some whitespace and nonwhitespace characters],
         [some whitespace and nonwhitespace characters],
         ....
         [some whitespace and nonwhitespace characters]],

"1001":[ [some whitespace and nonwhitespace characters],
         [some whitespace and nonwhitespace characters],
         ....
         [some whitespace and nonwhitespace characters]],
...
}
```

and I want to extract a record like the one shown below using regex :

```
"1000":[ [some whitespace and nonwhitespace characters],
         [some whitespace and nonwhitespace characters],
             ....
         [some whitespace and nonwhitespace characters]]
```

I'm doing this in **python** using **re** module

Now for this I have in my mind the pattern :

```
' "[0-9]{4}":(anything except ]] ) '
```

but I can't figure out what will be the pattern for **anything except ']]'**

could anyone help?

Comment: Where does the string come from? Is it actually JSON? Could you give an actual sample? Have you considered a *"negative lookahead"*?

Comment: Seems like parsing this as JSON and extracting the relevant keys would be better than trying to use regex.

Comment: [`"[0-9]{4}":(.*?]\s*])`](https://regex101.com/r/fP5oP4/1)

Comment: no the problem is with figuring out the expression for not ']]' I had tried the expression ' "[0-9]{4}":(?!\]\]).* ' but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: I doubt if you are talking about the right phrase: it's not *anything except* but *anything up to*

Comment: also one more thing is that json file is very large and even using ijson for parsing records takes a lot of time so i'm taking some part of the json file, only the one that is relevant and then extracting the record using regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex solution can be achieved using something like:

```
\d{4}":(.*?)]]
```

But you really *don't* want to use regex here if your string is a valid JSON. It's very natural for Python to work with JSONs. Assuming your data is:

```
data = {key1: [[str1], [str2], ...], ...}
```

You can simply grab the value of `key1` by accessing the corresponding key:

```
data[key1]
```

this will give you:

Comment: This help @Maroun , Thanks but the problem is due to large json file size it can't be stored in a single object and also parsing with ijson takes time so i'm applying this regex only on the relevant part of json file to extract data needed.

Comment: I would think the regex would be something more of `"\d{4}":([\s\S]+?)]]` since he did say _anything_ so that includes line breaks?

Comment: @MoonCheesez that's true. OP can also pass `re.DOTALL`.